# Best Practice for handling multiple authentication providers for MVC ala stackoverflow

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, facebook, asp.net-membership, twitter

I'm looking for suggestions on how to handle multiple auth providers like twitter, facebook, google, openid within an MVC app.

What is the general idea? I've got my own user detail table and i'm currently using ASP.Net membership authentication.

When someone connects with facebook are you able to extract user detail information from them via a cookie or directly from facebook? Do people typically store this in their local database?

I guess i'm looking for a broad overview. I've read some tutorials but they generally deal with specific details with connecting. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is OpenId support. As an example, you could refer to NerdDinner code from http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/

Also see http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/

Comment: Awesome thanks! I'm going to spend some time investigating but does this library help with facebook connect in any way?? I guess it helps layout the general architecture?

Comment: Glad, I could help.
OpenId is a standard so I believe this should work as long as the site supports OpenId for login. I do not have experience with Facebook API but it is used by Linq2Twitter (another project on codeplex for LINQ api's for twitter, this included login).

Comment: @toddm Just wondering, did you ever managed it to work? I'm thinking of starting a site and would like to integrate facebook and twitter auth too